# Best practice to add object to a list on ajax post success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am building a website that performs CRUD operations using ASP.NET Core, jQuery and AJAX.

I have two ways of adding an object to a table from an AJAX success function:

1) The MVC Controller will return Partial View with the updated list.

```
return PartialView("_ScheduleList", listOfSchedules);
```

and the partial view is loaded in success callback function as..

```js
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST', 
url: '/Schedule/Create', 
data: info, 
success: function(response){
$("#scheduleList").html(response);
}});
```

2) MVC Controller returns object and the object is appended to the table.

```
return Json(createdSchedule);
```

```js
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST', 
url: '/Schedule/Create', 
data: info, 
success: function(response){
var html = "";
html += "<div>";
html += `<p>${response.title}</p>`;
html += "</div>";
$("#scheduleList").append(html);
}});
```

Both methods work fine.  I find the first method easier but from what I've read, returning Partial Views constitutes as bad practice. The second method is error prone if not written carefully. My question is which method is the better/conventional approach and why?

Comment: Why do you consider returning a partial view bad practice?

Comment: Both are best practices. Usage depends on your purpose. The first method is more suitable for code maintainability.

Comment: @Fran I shouldn't have used the term bad practice, sorry about that. What I meant was since the server returns the refreshed list, it uses more data compared to the second method which only returns a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your purpose

- If the amount of data returned is large, then you should use method 2, as it will reduce the amount of data from the server returned to the client. The speed of return will be faster.
- If the html code is complex, you need genarate html under many logical conditions, then you should use the first method